# calculation of $\mathbb{E}[X_k^2]$ for independent random variables identically distributed

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given the set $\{X_k: k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ that consists of  independent random variables identically distributed with the distribution function $F(x)$.  We have $\mathbb{E}[X_k^2] < \infty$. So suppose that $X_k \geq 0$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then we can write (our lecture notes):

$$\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}(1-F(\sqrt{x}))dx=\int_\limits{0}^\infty \int_\limits{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty} dF(y) dx=\int_\limits{0}^\infty \int_\limits{0}^{y^2}dx dF(y)=\int_\limits{0}^\infty y^2 dF(y)=\mathbb{E}[X_k^2].$$

The third equation is clear because of Fubini's Theorem. But I don't understand the first and second equation. How can they change the boundaries?
Why are $\sqrt{x} \leq F(y) \leq \infty$ and $0 \leq x \leq  \infty$  equivalent to $0 \leq F(y) \leq \infty$ and $0 \leq \sqrt{x} \leq y$?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality follows from the fact that 
$$1-F\left(\sqrt{x}\right)= \mathbb P\left(X_1>\sqrt x\right)=\int_{\sqrt{x}}^\infty dF(y).$$
For the second equation, we write the double integral as 
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{\{\sqrt x\lt y\}}dxdF(y)
$$
and use the fact that $\mathbf 1_{\{\sqrt x\lt y\}}=\mathbf 1_{\{  x\lt y^2\}}$ since $x,y\geqslant 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It helps me a lot. Do you know how they changed the boundaries in the 2nd equation?

Comment: Yes. I edited the post.